# How can I get the old value by using updateOrCreate?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I use the `updateOrCreate` function to update my database.

```php
Data::updateOrCreate([
    'variable_id'     => $var_id,
    'instance_id' => $instance_id],[
    'value'    => $value,
]);
```

I would like to retrieve the old value. I understood that we could use `getOriginal()`. But in my case, `getOriginal()` returns the last updated value and not the old value.

Do you know why?

Comment: I would think it is because you only get the new updated values in the model, getOriginal would work if you used fill(). So you would have to make some logic to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

If you refresh your model in any way after persisting it to the database, you'll get the value stored in the database:

```php
$object = Object::find(1);
dump($object->name); // John

$object->updateOrCreate(['id', 1], ['name' => 'Frank']);
dump($object->getOriginal('name')); // John

$object->refresh();
dump($object->getOriginal('name')); // Frank
```

Comment: Am using laravel 5.7 it says `Method getorginal does not exist`

Comment: @DaniyalNasir Then why have you used the `laravel-8` tag? Regardless, the [`getOriginal`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_getOriginal) method is available in Laravel 5.7.

Comment: Pepper Am not OP.

Comment: @DaniyalNasir Apologies, neither you are. Previous comment regarding the `getOriginal` method being available in Laravel 5.7 remains valid though.